# Proof that Vector Space in Domain of Linear Map is a Direct Sum

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

I'm working through problems in Linear Algebra just for fun and I am getting stuck on Axler 3.4.

Suppose that $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to $\mathbf{F}$. Prove that if $u \in V$ is not in $null\ T$, then 
\begin{align*}
V=null\ T \oplus \left\{au:a\in F\right\}
\end{align*}

My proof so far:

Suppose that $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to $\mathbf{F}$ and $u \in V$ is not in $null\ T$. We know that $Tu \neq 0$ since 
$u \notin null\ T$. Since $T$ is a linear map, $T(au)=aTu$. $aT(u)=0$ only when $a = 0$ since $Tu \neq 0$. Therefore, we 
can show that 
\begin{align*}
null\ T \cap \left\{au: a \in F\right\} = \left\{0\right\}
\end{align*}
Let $v \in V$ be any vector. We want to show that $V=null\ T + \left\{au: a \in F\right\}$.

This is where I am getting stuck. I have tried using the linearity and homogeneity property of linear maps but I'm not getting anywhere. I would really appreciate a hint on how to proceed and solve this problem!

Comment: Is $F$ the field that $V$ is over?

Comment: In the book I'm using F is the field of complex or real numbers (R or C); V is also over F.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices to complete your proof

- the easiest is to notice using the rank nullity theorem that
  $$\dim V=\dim\ker T+\dim\operatorname{span}(u)$$
- the second way is: let $x\in V$ so
  $$x=\underbrace{x-\frac{Tx}{Tu}u}_{\in\ker T}+\underbrace{\frac{Tx}{Tu}u}_{\in\operatorname{span}(u)}$$

Comment: Thank you. I like both of your approaches though I'll complete my proof by using the second approach.

Comment: You're welcome.